# How to deploy flask socket application to google cloud

Tags: python, flask, deployment, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

My `web_app.py` has the following content (only most relevant information included):

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, ping_timeout=1200)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    socketio.run(app)
```

My `app.yaml` is:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT web_app:socketio

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.6

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
skip_files:
- output/
- data/
- .idea/
- env/
```

When I run `gcloud app deploy` I get the following error:

```
Application object must be callable.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app.yaml file, when running gunicorn, you have to indicate the name of the flask class of your web app. [Here](http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), under deployment, you can find some different options to deploy a Flask-SocketIO server.
You should replace `entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT web_app:socketio` for `entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT web_app:app`